# How do I link to my GCS Bucket JSON credentials file in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, google-cloud-storage

I am using the Django-gcloud-storage library to allow my Django app to store images on GCS.

I already created a bucket, GCS service account and downloaded a JSON keyfile according [to the guide](https://pypi.org/project/django-gcloud-storage/). However, saving an image to the Cloud storage raises this error:

```
AssertionError at /showroom/create/
Credentials file not found

...

/srv/showroom/views.py in form_valid
                images.save() …
▶ Local vars
...
/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_gcloud_storage/__init__.py in __init__
        assert os.path.exists(self.credentials_file_path), "Credentials file not found" …
▶ Local vars
```

(showroom/create is the upload form).

I stored my JSON credentials file in my static folder `static/js/torque-xxx-02827c7cc0ad.json`

**settings.py**

```
GCS_PROJECT = "torque-xxx"

GCS_BUCKET = "torque-xxx.appspot.com"

GCS_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'js', 'torque-xxx-02827c7cc0ad.json')
# GCS_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = '/static/js/torque-xxx-02827c7cc0ad.json' ## This was my first try, didn't work

# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'google.storage.googleCloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_gcloud_storage.DjangoGCloudStorage'
```

I'm very unfamiliar with Cloud storage and APIs, so forgive me if this is a novice question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Right out of the box, `BASE_DIR` is the folder containing the `manage.py` module.

Check to confirm that there is a static folder there.

> Storing GCS credentials file in static files presents a security risk as it contains your service account key.

Usually, it can be stored in other locations that can't publicly be accessed.

In line with [12 factor application methodology](https://12factor.net/config), I suggest to configure an environment variable and write its contents there.

You could do this in an `env_file` or simply export to your shell environment.

```sh
export GCS_CREDENTIALS=`cat /path-to-gcs-credentials-file`
```

Then write from the environment variable to a file in a location other than `static` folder in your `settings` module.

```py
# Load environment variables from env_file if any
# https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)


# This could be any path that the application has read/write permission to
GCS_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.gcs_credentials_file') 
with open(GCS_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, 'w') as f:
    f.write(os.getenv('GCS_CREDENTIALS'))
```

Also remember to leave out `.gcs_credentials_file` or whatever name you decide for the file from version control.

Answer (score 0):

All Google Credentials Key need to be stored in environment variables. For example, you should create a `.env` file like this.

**.env**

`GCS_CREDENTIALS=<your credentials key>`

And then in Django, you can do something like this

`os.getenv('GCS_CREDENTIALS')`

Comment: How exactly does a env file work? Do I create a new file with a.env extension within the project?

Comment: ```.env``` is like a file that store your environment variables. Basically, it gives you a better control of what environment variables are used in your app/service. It works like ```expose $GSC_CREDENTIALS = <your key>```